# C program for below pyramid If possible JAVA code also

Tags: c

**Desired Output**

```
    1234554321
    1234__4321
    123____321
    12______21
    1________1
```

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,c,sp,r=1;
    printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\n");
    for(; num>=1; num--,r++)
    {
        for(c=1; c<=num; c++)
            printf("%d",c);
        for(sp=r; sp>1; sp--)
            printf("_");
        for(sp=r; sp>1; sp--)
            printf("_");
        for(c=num; c>=1; c--)
            printf("%d",c);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I am looking for other alternative codes which are less complex. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you reading `num` from stdin rather than taking it as an argument?

Comment: Someone please fix the indentation; every time I try someone else edits the question and I can't save mine.

Comment: This question should probably go to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines are symmetrical. You can use a recursive function where you print before and after recursing to achieve this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void line(int i, int n, int m)
{
    if (i < n) {
        putchar(i > m ? '_' : '0' + (i + 1) % 10);
        line(i + 1, n, m);
        putchar(i > m ? '_' : '0' + (i + 1) % 10);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, n = 0;

    if (argc > 1) n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n <= 0) n = 5;

    i = n;
    while (i--) {
        line(0, n, i);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The lines themselves are controlled with a regular loop. The newline `'\n'` can't be part of the recursive function, because it doesn't fit the symmetric pattern; it has to be printed explicitly. This version takes the size of the pyramid from the command line with a default of 5.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than making multiple calls to printf, it seems cleaner to construct the string yourself:

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                        
#include<stdlib.h>                                                       

int                                                                      
main( int argc, char ** argv )                                           
{                                                                        
        unsigned num = argc > 1 ? strtol( argv[1], NULL, 0 ) : 5;          
        char digits[] = "123456789_987654321";                           
        char *rhs = digits + sizeof digits - 1 - num;                    

        if( num > 9 ) {                                                  
                fprintf( stderr, "argument must be < 10" );              
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );                                    
        }                                                                
        digits[num] = '\0';                                              
        for( ; num > 0; ) {                                              
                printf( "%s%s\n", digits, rhs );                         
                digits[ sizeof digits - 1 - num ] = '_';                 
                digits[ --num ] = '_';                                     
        }                                                                
        return 0;                                                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\n");

    for (int row = 0; row < num; ++row) {
        int columnLimit = num - row;
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnLimit; ++column) {
            printf("%d", column);
        }
        for(int spacing = 0; spacing < row; ++spacing) {
            printf("__");
        }
        for (int column = columnLimit; column > 0; --column) {
            printf("%d", column);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[IDE One](http://ideone.com/hgtRvP)

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator for simplification, this way you only need two lines 
inside of the inner loop code,

```
val = column <= num ? column : limit - column + 1;
printf("%c", val > row ? '_' : val + 0x30);
```

Here it is:

```
int main(){
    int num,column,row,limit,val;
    printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\n");
    limit = num * 2;
    for (row = num; row > 0; --row){ //num times
        for (column = 1; column <= limit; ++column){
            val = column <= num ? column : limit - column + 1;
            printf("%c", val > row ? '_' : val + 0x30);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

The downside is you still have to call printf multiple times. But obviously the code is really compact!

Comment: ...or... you could use if-else instead, together with sensible variable names.

Comment: @Lundin var names edited

Answer (score 1):

A revisited one that asks the user for the max number...

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows, 9 max): ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if (num > 9) num = 9;

    int i,j;
    for (i=num ; i>0 ; i--) {
       for(j=1 ; j<=num ; j++) {
          printf("%c", j>i ? '_':0x30+j);
       }
       for(j=num ; j>=1 ; j--) {
          printf("%c", j>i ? '_':0x30+j);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`0x30` is the ascii code for `0`, adding `j` gives `1` to `num`.

---

**edit** a *recursive* bonus ...

```
int num; // global to avoid putting it in the recursive function

void recursive(int i, int j) {
    printf("%c", i>j ? '_':0x30+i);
    if (i<num) recursive(i+1, j);
    printf("%c", i>j ? '_':0x30+i);
    if(i==1) {
        printf("\n");
        if (--j > 0) recursive(1, j);
    }
}
```

To be called as `recursive(1, num);`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows, 9 max): ");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   if (num > 9) num = 9;

   recursive(1, num);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LPs Isn't the output supposed to be 5 lines only?

Comment: Updated with an added recursive version! That should fit ✈

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,c,sp;
    printf("\n");
    for(num =5; num>=1; num--)
    {
        for(c=1; c<=5; c++)
        {
            if(c>num)
            {
                printf("_");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d",c);
            }
        }
        for(c=5; c>=1; c--)
        {
            if(c>num)
            {
                printf("_");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d",c);
            } 
        }    

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (but not checking!) that input does not exceed 9:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num, r, c;
    printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\n");
    for(r=num; r>=1; row--)
    {
        for(c=1; c<=num; c++)
            putc(c<=r ? ('0'+c) : '_');
        for(c=num; c>=1; c--)
            putc(c<=r ? ('0'+c) : '_');
        putc("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works until 9 rows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, cols;
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter loop repeat number(rows): ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\n");

    if (num<10)
    {
        cols=num*2;

        char **matrix = malloc(num*sizeof(char *));

        for(i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(char *));

            memset(matrix[i], '_', cols);

            for (j=0; j<num; j++)
            {
                if (j<(num-i))
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = (j+1)+0x30;
                    matrix[i][cols-j-1] = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<cols; j++)
                printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);

            printf("\n");

            free(matrix[i]);
        }

        free(matrix);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Max allowed rows = 9\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[IDE One](http://ideone.com/lnGtFp)

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to assume that it won't go above an input of 9, so I'll assume the same ...

```
int num=5; // Set as required

int  max=9;
char leftNums[10] = "123456789";
char rightNums[10] = "987654321";
char pyramid[17] = "________________";

int rightStart = max - num;
for (int row=0; row<num; row++) {
    int colLimit = num - row;
    printf("%*.*s", colLimit, colLimit, leftNums);
    printf("%*.*s", 2*row, 2*row, pyramid);
    printf("%*.*s\n", colLimit, colLimit, &rightNums[rightStart+row]);
    // Or, if you prefer for the last line:
    // printf("%*.*s\n", colLimit, colLimit, rightNums+rightStart+row);
}
```

Notes:

- You can obviously easily play around with letters, numbers and so on in this approach.
- If you want to go above 9, you'll probably want to use letters rather than numbers ...

[IDEone.com](http://ideone.com/3MZucy)